# how can I make my ubuntu machine discoverable by name for ssh from other linux machines?

Tags: networking, ssh, samba

I cannot ssh to my ubuntu laptop by host name from other linux machines on the network.  My ubuntu laptop is a member of the corporate domain and can see all the other network computers.  I can putty to it from windows computers by name but when I try to ssh to it by name from another linux machine I get the error:

ssh: Could not resolve hostname SOMETHING: Name or service not known

How do I make it discoverable to linux machines on the network?

I've tried changing the smb.conf file to include netbios name = SOMETHING, and I've tried changing the dns proxy = DNS ADDRESS followed by a restart of the samba server, but neither or both yielded any results.  I'm running Ubuntu 13.10.

Thanks,
Cole

Answer (score 3):

If you're running some kind of shared folder system  like samba, the machine is discoverable using the local domain, try something like:

```
ssh nameofthemachine.local
```

If not, you'll need to setup some DNS local server either in the network or in the ssh server itself to translate domain names into IP's.